Use ellipsis to hide overflow, but also allow wordwrapping, if there is vertical space
I have boxes in various sizes and want to display a name in them, as good as possible.
Here is some code I use for testing purposes:


    div {
      display:flex;
      background:yellow;
      border: 2px solid orange;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height:30px;
      width:100px;
      vertical-align:middle;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
      text-align:center;
      overflow:hidden;
      text-overflow:ellipsis;
      margin:20px;
    }
    
    div > span {
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    
    <div style="width:100px; height:75px;">
      <span>Short Name</span>
    </div>
    
    <div style="width:100px; height:75px;">
      <span>Long Name, very very long Name</span>
    </div>
    
    <div style="width:25px; height:25px;">
      <span>This will not fit and should be ellipsed like "T..."</span>
    </div>



In this version I really like how the very short "T..." displays. It makes sense for super short boxes to be truncated after the first letter like that. However, the middle one would have enough space to wrap and display.
If I remove the white-space:nowrap, then the middle one looks good, but the bottom one looks very bad (displaying something like "a..." from the middle of the name, instead of using the start).
Is there a way to combine the best of both worlds, to get the bottom one show as "T..." like in the first fiddle, and let the middle one wrap like in the second fiddle? (The top box looks equally good in both versions, full name in center)
jsfiddle 1 (with white-space:nowrap)
jsfiddle 2 (without white-space:nowrap)

To clarify, something like this would be the desired output:


you rigth i just check it on chrome and did not work
